# How to determine whether a Java collection contains `null`

Tags: java, collections

I want to write a method which takes a collection as a parameter. However, the collection cannot contain `null`. If it contains `null`, this will lead to a NullPointerException later on, when it is not clear anymore where the `null` came from. Therefore, I want to validate the input. The naive approach would be:

```
public void doSomething(Collection<?> collection) {
    if (collection.contains(null))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("collection cannot contain null!");

    // do something
}
```

However, `Collection.contains` may throw a NullPointerException if the collection does not support `null` values. In fact, Java's own immutable collections do that. So, in the naive approach, the following code does not work:

```
doSomething(List.of("a", "b", "c")); // NullPointerException!
```

There are a few possible solutions, but none of them feel right.

For example, I could search for `null` myself:

```
public void doSomething(Collection<?> collection) {
    for (var e : collection) {
        if (e == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("collection cannot contain null!");
    }
    // do something
}
```

But now I'm doing a linear search, although the collection might be a HashSet or a TreeSet, offering much better performance.

Or I could catch the NullPointerException:

```
public void doSomething(Collection<?> collection) {
    try {
        if (collection.contains(null))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("collection cannot contain null!");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Apparently, collection doesn't support null. This is good!
    }
    // do something
}
```

But this feels very unsafe. Can I really be sure that that NullPointerException was caused by the collection not supporting nulls, or did I just eat an Exception which could provide valuable information on a bug?

Is there a good way to determine whether a collection contains `null`?

Comment: Lets take a moment to think about what other reasons you might get for a NullPointerException when using contains on a collection. As far as I can think of the only other time would be if the collection itself is null. Therefore it at least to me seems like a good option UNLESS you need to do something else in a situation where your collection is null

Comment: Why do you think, an `IllegalArgumentException` with a message that tells us that the problem is a `null` is better than a `NullPointerException` which intrinsically tells us that the problem is a `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think, replacing a `NullPointerException` with an `IllegalArgumentException` is an improvement. It requires us to read a message to get an information the dedicated exception type tells us intrinsically.

Of course, checking incoming arguments as early as possible, to avoid detaching the source of the problem from the place where the exception occurs, is a good thing. When I use, e.g.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NullCheckExample().doSomething(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", null));
}

public void doSomething(Collection<?> collection) {
    collection.forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);

    // do something
}
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
    at NullCheckExample.doSomething(NullCheckExample.java:12)
    at NullCheckExample.main(NullCheckExample.java:8)
```

which I consider it expressive enough, to help tracing the cause.

Now, is there a way to avoid the costs of a linear search when `null` is impossible? In theory, yes. We can do

```java
public void doSomething(Collection<?> collection) {
    Spliterator<?> sp = collection.spliterator();
    if(sp.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.NONNULL)) {
        // yeah, null is impossible
    }
    else if(sp.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED) && sp.getComparator() == null) {
        // natural order precludes null too
    }
    else {
        // here we have to check,
        // collection.forEach(Objects::requireNonNull)
        // or 
        // if(collection.contains(null)) throw ...
    }

    // do something
}
```

which does work for some collections, e.g. the concurrent collections or a `TreeSet`. The problem is, it doesn’t work for `List.of(…)` or `Set.of(…)` kind of collections. In the reference implementation (OpenJDK), the `spliterator`  method has not been overridden, which not only means that Stream operations are less efficient, we also do not get `NONNULL` nor `IMMUTABLE` characteristics.

So in these cases, we end up doing an unnecessary linear search or have to deal with `contains(null)` throwing a `NullPointerException` (in the common case, rather than the erroneous case).

Depending on what you want to do, you might do something like

```java
public void doSomething(Collection<?> collection) {
    List<?> workingCopy = List.copyOf(collection);

    // do something
}
```

This bears a copy operation, but does protect you against subsequent modifications of the collection, which might be needed anyway, to ensure consistency. The working copy is guaranteed to be free of `null` and not to change. If the caller passes the result of `List.of(…)` into this method, which fulfills the criteria already, the `copyOf` will become a no-op, just returning the argument. So this is the best option when you expect the input to be an immutable list already most of the times.

But if you’re going to say that neither is a satisfying solution, I’d agree. There should be efficient possibilities to preclude `null`. Rejecting attempts to query for `null` is fine, but it should not end up in having no way to efficiently ensure that there is no `null`. It’s also baffling that there are no efficient `spliterator()` nor `forEach` implementations for the immutable collections, despite their implementations would be very simple, one-liners in most cases.

Comment: The kind of Exception was indeed not the reason why I asked the question, but the time when the exception is thrown. I prefer to get the exception at the time when I'm doing something wrong (I'm passing a collection which contains null) rather than later (which may even be during a different method call), when a null element turns up and I have to determine where that null came from.

Answer (score 1):

`list.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)`

`true` if it contains null-values

Answer (score 0):

If your Java version is >= 8, you can use the stream API:

```
List<YourObject> newList = userListCollection.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

I think, the stream() method is optimised for each collection type, so you shouldn't face performance issues. However, you still have to check if the whole collection is null.

Comment: Streams do no magic. This still is processing all elements, precisely what the OP wants to avoid. And, as surprising as it may be, in case of the immutable collections, i.e. `List.of(…)` case, which the OP mentioned, the stream is not optimized.