# Java stream - elegant way to do stream on nullable list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-stream, option-type

This has been troubling me for a while.
So I have a `Product` class that has a list of `Image` (the list could be null).
I want to do

```java
product.getImages().stream().filter(...)
```

But as `product.getImages()` could be null, I can't directly do above but have to wrap it with `Optional.ofNullable(...).ifPresent(...)`

```java
Optional.ofNullable(product.getImages())
    .ifPresent(imgs->imgs.stream().filter(...))
```

To me it looks cumbersome even when compared to:

```java
if(product.getImages() != null){
    product.getImages().stream().filter(...)
}
```

Assuming I can't change `Product::getImages` (to make it not return null), is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Does `ifPresent` actually work for you? Don't you want a result from the stream operations? If you use `ifPresent` you won't be able to get that result.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68859507/2310289

Comment: List is a container, which can't be null. Just send an empty list instead. You don't need optionals here. If you don't have any control over that method, just do a null check first before proceed.

Comment: **The list really shouldn't be `null`.** A list which could be null is not elegant in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [`Optional.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--), which gives you an empty stream if the optional is empty, otherwise it is a singleton stream of the element wrapped by the optional.

You can do something like:

```
Stream<Image> imageStream = 
    Optional.ofNullable(product.getImages())
        .stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(...);
```

`imageStream` will be empty if `getImages` returns null.

There is also [`Stream.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#ofNullable-T-) (thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for reminding me!), which can replace `Optional.ofNullable(product.getImages()).stream()`

```
Stream<Image> imageStream = 
    Stream.ofNullable(product.getImages())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(...);
```