# How to safely test an unknown collection for null elements in Java?

Tags: java, collections, nullable

Easy task, isn't it? Or?

There is a little sentence in the Collection.contains contract, that makes it less easy:

> @throws NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and
> this collection does not permit null elements (optional)

A small notice, with big impact. I didn't pay much attention to it, until I come across collections exhibiting this optional behavior, namely immutable collections new to Java 9. Later I found out that other not so commonly used implementations behave that way too, namely SortedSet implementations.

So, again, what's wrong on asking a collection if it contains nulls? If the collection is of unknown origin, I don't now if it *permits* null values, I even cannot know it, and I don't care, anyway.

Do I really need to do

```
return set.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)
```

Or even

```
try {
    set.contains(null);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return false;
}
```

What point am I missing here? Why this optional behavior was introduced to the contract?

Comment: Is my assumption correct that you expect such collections to `if(null == element) return false;` instead of supposing that the test element is eligible to be stored to start with...? If so (and if you can set aside the "`Collection`" contract for now), what would be your reason (other than your code doesn't care)?

Comment: I don't know If I got your point. (1) I expect the collection to just return false if it does not contain (and e.g. does not even permit) null element. I don't care how this is implemented. If testing null value would crash the implementation, the null check may be needed. For instance, Guava ImmutableList does not have this check, and I suppose it would normally return false.

Comment: (2) what would be the reason for what? For the need to test the presence of null elements in an unknown collection? I think it's not so important, I admit it is somehow an edge case, but at times you may need it and I still think its a legitimate check.

Comment: Why do you think that this NPE should not be on the contract? Don't get me wrong, I find it annoying too; but you're questioning behavior that was deliberately introduced, so we need to have reasons other than "it's annoying" or "at this level, the contract shouldn't be concerned with abstracted-away implementation-specific properties"

Comment: And just BTW, I could find this `throws` even in [JavaDocs of `Collection` in Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Comment: I don't question it was deliberate (I believe so), I just don't get the justification for it. I am just surprised that you just *cannot* do this test on an unknown collection. I wouldn't call it annoying, it seems just wrong to me. I am more surprised that I wasn't aware of this flaw until today, 18 years after Java 5 release, after everyday usage of Java :) Perhaps because most implementations just did not follow this "recommendation", Guava to name one.

Comment: BTW, the fact that in boolean contains(Object o) the argument is typed to Object, was specifically to be able to test for elements that the collection does not permit in terms of type. The other "optional" behavior suprised me also - a collection *may* throw CCE if you are asking for the presence of an element that it does not permit in terms of type. I doubt many collections do that - and even can do dat - which makes this "option" even worse.

Comment: I think the case of `CCE` is even more prevalent, relatively speaking. You can produce it by checking `coll.contains("")` with `coll` being a `TreeSet<Integer>`; as an example. I think the worse part of this *throws* clause is that it's on `Collection`. I wouldn't mind it when using `TreeSet` or some immutable collection type directly. Making `Collection.contains` allow it makes the behavior a little arbitrary, at least as far as the contract is concerned.

Comment: `TreeSet<String> t = new TreeSet<>(); t.add("foo"); t.contains(42);`

Comment: Oh, ernest_k was faster. Anyway, I think [How to determine whether a Java collection contains `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68859095/2711488) covers most of your concerns already. But it’s not as if the answer will be satisfying. It’s rather acknowledging that the current situation is bad.

Comment: Oh, duplicate. And I really tried to find this one :) Thanks @Holger. Also for the CCE example. I think that the optional, arbitrary behavior is the worst part of it, it really doesn't help anyone. Otherwise there is no doub't you must follow the contracts, even the ill-designed ones.

Comment: The problem is that the methods were designed long before generics were introduced. And when this API was generified, there were compatibility concerns. Changing `add(Object)` to `add(T)` was an accepted break of compatibility, because trying to add an incompatible object is a clear mistake that will backfire later. Probing for an object that is definitely absent is a different category, still, whether `contains(Object)` should have been changed to `contains(T)` is controversial…

Comment: I reformulated the question a little bit. The point of the question is to point out the fact that collection.contains(null) is an unsafe operation, which is sort of counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: I would merge this with [How to determine whether a Java collection contains \`null\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68859095/how-to-determine-whether-a-java-collection-contains-null) - as Holger says, it covers essentially the same problem.

Comment: Well, the discussion goes in a slightly different direction, but the question is essentially the same. Ok, we can merge.

Answer (score 1):

After a discussion, I would say, the correct answer is:

```
collection.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)
```

That is, if there is a code with the statement

```
collection.contains(nullable)
```

in a context where collection is an unknown implementation of Collection, and nullable is a nullable variable/expression, then this is likely an error. A rather insidious error, because implementations are free to decide whether to react with false or NPE, if they do not permit null values.

Comment: The  stream approach is O(N), while with a suitable catch, the `contains` approach can be O(1). I hate using exceptions for flow control, and agree that the API here is a problem (Java API designers also [seem to agree](https://stuartmarks.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/marks-collectionsyoungpups-v2.pdf)). But with a suitable disclaimer, I would use the exception route.

Comment: Thats right. I hate that too. You can choose whether to shoot yourself in the leg or arm, and the problem is the API. Catching NPE is legitimate option, less elegant, but likely (much) more efficient.

Comment: @tucuxi Your link is a very interesting reading!!! The Java API designers seem to agree much farther than the OP :) "Allowing nulls in collections back in 1.2 was a mistake". And I agree that the exception would be in general more efficient, however ugly it is :)

Comment: I agree with that. It was bad idea to allow nulls in collections at all. Its perfectly ok that some implementations refuse null elements. Or elements of wrong type. Or whatever they choose. But for *mutation* operations. My whole point is, that it is IMO bad idea to refuse *test* operations, based on they are not eligible for the collection if you can simply return false. Worse, it is an *option* to fail on these tests. And worst, implementation authors decided to seize this option.

Comment: > 1. "it is bad idea to refuse test operations" - 100% agreed. > 2. "Worse, it is an option to fail on these tests" - 100% agreed. > 3. "And worst, implementation authors decided to seize this option." -  - 100% agreed.  :)